# Cannot add Switzerland trip to travel history in my UK visa application

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, switzerland

I'm filling my UK visa application and at travel history question I have added several countries to my application but am stuck at Switzerland.

I visited Switzerland at 2012 but I cannot find it in the country list and I cannot added manually. Can anybody help me with that?

Additional information that might help: it was not a Schengen visa, but Swiss visa type C.

Comment: Are you applying through VFS or the gov.uk site? Possibly a system error - there’s no reason why Switzerland would not appear in the country list AFAIK.

Comment: You may find switzerland in other places, e.g. near C (for CH country code), or try to imagine that the list was created in an other language (and so sorting), and not in the displayed language. Try to look again near C and S, out of order (of alphabet)

Comment: Consider H like `Helvetia` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetia

Comment: In Dutch, Switzerland is *Zwitserland.*  Confusing, I know!  If you find the answer yourself, please post an answer below.

Comment: There are multiple sections for travel history: one for the UK, one for the US, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, EEA and Switzerland, and a final one for other countries. Travel to Switzerland goes into the second one, not the last.

Comment: Thank you all for your replay, Thanks @jcaron I found it at the second one not the last

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple sections for travel history:

- one for the UK
- one for the US, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, EEA **and Switzerland**
- and a final one for other countries.

Travel to Switzerland goes into the second one, not the last.